# How To Define a JPA Repository Query with a Join and Concat

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql, concatenation

I want to select Autor, and Concat the Mangas.

I tried use GROUP_CONCAT() but dont work in AutorRepository.

```
#AutorRepository
@Query("Select a,  GROUP_CONCAT(m.nome) FROM AutorEntity a, MangasEntity m ")
            List<AutorEntity> buscarAutorEMangas();

#AutorController
     @RequestMapping(value="/autor1", method= RequestMethod.GET)
                    public List<AutorEntity> ProcurarAutorEManga(){
                        return autorRepository.buscarAutorEMangas();
                    }

#Table Autor    
    @Entity
        @Table(name = "Autor")
        public class AutorEntity {

            private Long id;
            private String nome;

            @JsonIgnore
            @ManyToOne  
            @JoinTable(name="mangas_autor",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="manga_id",referencedColumnName="id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="autor_id",referencedColumnName="id"))

            private List<MangasEntity> manga;

#Table Mangas    
 @Entity
        @Table(name = "Mangas")
        public class MangasEntity implements Serializable{

            private Long id;
            private String nome;
            private  Status status;
            private Date dataLancado;    
            private AutorEntity autor;  
            private List<GenerosEntity> genero

        @OneToMany(cascade= CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="autor")
        public List<MangasEntity> getManga() {
            return manga;
        }
```

Query in MySQL, Select AUTOR and CONCAT Manga name

SELECT a.*, GROUP_CONCAT(m.nome)
FROM autor a
JOIN mangas_autor ma
ON ma.autor_id=a.id
JOIN mangas m
ON ma.manga_id=m.id
GROUP BY a.nome

How select Autor and get the Mangas of each autor?

Any Idea,please?

Comment: JPQL has no such "GROUP_CONCAT", so why be surprised at an error? http://www.datanucleus.org:15080/products/accessplatform_5_1/jpa/query.html#jpql_functions   JPQL != SQL, as any JPA documentation or the JPA spec would reveal

Comment: It work, but i have a problem, i use @JsonIgnore on Table Author reference List <MangasEntity>, so can not return to list with many Mangas, The Query get duplicated Mangas. [photo about return](https://i.imgur.com/rxyEB52.jpg)